# How to use xml data stored by saveAs option in gatling

Tags: xml, gatling

One of my gatling request returning xml data. I have to pass subset of that xml response into body of next request.

I fetched and saved xml subset like this:

```scala
 .check(xpath("metadata/metadata1/metadata2").saveAs("config")
```

Now my xml data is stored in String format.

Next request's body part is expecting data in xml format only.
I tried below for this:

```scala
  .body(StringBody("""${config}"""))
```

But xml data is not getting passed here.

What is wrong? Is there any other better way to get xml response and pass it's subset as body of next request?

Answer (score 0):

XML is a format that's so complex that it would be very complicated to provide a generic solution for what you're trying to do. It's not just about copying the part of the tree: what about namespaces?

So basically, you can't do it with current XPath support in Gatling.

I see the following possible solutions:

1. Use a regular expression.
2. Capture the values you're interested in separately with xpath, save them, and use them to build a request body with a template. This solution is not generic though.
3. If you're proficient with XML APIs, you can use a bodyString check, and parse it yourself in a transform step.